# テーブル行上のYes/No形式のラジオボタン、行単位の入力値管理方法を教えてください。

Tags: php, html, jquery

Yes/No形式のラジオボタンを列挙する場合、双方同じname属性のラジオボタン（input要素）にせざるを得ないと思いますが、テーブルの行上でこれらを配置する場合かつ、『行単位で異なる入力を達成したい』際には　どういった要素定義の仕方をしたらよろしいのでしょうか？

現在、全行で単一の入力しか行えない=どこかの行で入力が果たされると、他の行の入力値が消えてしまう状況となっています。（隣のチェックボックスは行単位の入力・識別が行えるようですが）

大変初歩的なことと思いますが、行単位にラジオボタンの入力値を維持できる方式を教えてください。

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" />
    </td>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cubickさんの　回答：`行ごとにINPUTのNAMEを変えるか`のサンプルを書いてみた。（なぜ？配列に拘る）

```
<?php
$flag = false;
for($i=1;$i < 6;$i++){
if(isset($_GET['status'.$i])){
    $flag = true;
    echo $_GET['status'.$i];
}
if(isset($_GET['del'.$i])){
    $flag = true;
    echo $_GET['del'.$i];
}
}
if($flag) exit;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="ttt.php">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
       1: <input type="radio" name="status1" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="status1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       2: <input type="radio" name="status2" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="status2" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del2" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       3: <input type="radio" name="status3" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="status3" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del3" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       4: <input type="radio" name="status4" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="status4" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del4" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       5: <input type="radio" name="status5" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="status5" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del5" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button name="a" type="submit" >aaaa</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: いつも大変お世話になっております。毎回お時間を頂きまして誠にありがとうございます。

【全行】に渡り行上の当該ラジオボタンの選択値によって区別された動作を行っていく予定ですが
こういった場合、PHP側でname属性を組み立てて行毎の選択値を見極めていくのが一般的、というとこですかね？

以前input type=textをtableの行へ格納してPHP側で内容取得した際、各々nameに[]を含めてHTML定義した記憶があります。
この経験から（PHP上では同目的と解釈される）行違いで要素を並べる際、nameに[]をつけるのが鉄板、
みたいに誤った理解をしている自分がいまして．．．．すみません。

Answer (score 0):

行ごとにINPUTのNAMEを変えるか

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" />
```

VALUEの値を工夫してみてはどうでしょうか。

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="q1_0" />
<input type="radio" name="status" value="q1_1" />
<input type="radio" name="status" value="q2_0" />
<input type="radio" name="status" value="q2_1" />
```

Comment: いつも大変御世話になっております、休日なのにすみません。
PHP側で、どの行についても当該項目に関わった条件式を通したいのですが
name属性を変えてしまうと条件式が一定にならない？！のかなぁという疑問もありまして．．．
試しにname属性に[]を付けても、動作は行全体で同一になってしまいました。

Comment: PHP側の事情が一切書かれていないので、現在の質問文だと回答者は考慮のしようがありません。二択であればラジオボタンでなくチェックボックスでも用は足りそうですが。